# programmatically set show_sql without recreating SessionFactory?

Tags: nhibernate

In NHibernate, I have `show_sql` turned on for running unit tests. Each of my unit tests clears the database and refills it, and this results in lots of sql queries that I don't want NHibernate to output.

Is it possible to control `show_sql` without destroying the `SessionFactory`? If possible, I'd like to turn it off when running setup for a test, then turn it on again when the body of the test starts to run.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you can set this is when building a **`NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration`**. 
Once you've created a `SessionFactory` from your `Configuration`, there's no way to access the configuration settings, which I think is one of the reasons for using a factory pattern: to ensure that instances once successfully built can't be messed up by runtime re- or mis-configuration.

If you really need that feature, get the NH source code and find the place where the show_sql setting is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Another option although it may/may not be as good is to use [NHProf](http://www.nhprof.com) and just  initialise NHProf when testing.

NHProf doesn't log setting/clearing database just queries used.